# VIM initial settings: change background color for line number on the left side?

Tags: vim

I use `_vimrc` to configure my vim 7.2 (windows) default settings. One setting "set number" will display line numbers on the left side. My vim background color is white (I cannot find setting for this. Maybe the default is white. Anyway I accept this setting).

I would like the background color for line numbers to be Grey or dimmed color. What is the command I can put in my `_vimrc` to configure this default setting?

Comment: robert and david refer to different settings - ctermbg and guibg. These are for command-line vim and graphical vim (gvim, macvim, etc), respectively. The following should cover both: `highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey ctermbg=black guibg=black guifg=grey`. Note that if you're using a GUI version of vim, `.gvimrc` color settings get applied second and can clobber the ones in `.vimrc`, so you might want to put the `guibg` etc settings there.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```vim
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey ctermbg=white
```

Comment: See also `:h highlight-args`. You may need `guifg`/`guibg` instead of `ctermfg`/`ctermbg` depending on your setup.

Answer (score 25):

To make the line number column transparent (the same color as the main background) you can try setting this in your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight clear LineNr
```

You can also clear the so-called sign column (used by gitgutter, etc) as well:

```
highlight clear SignColumn
```

This way, no matter what color scheme you use, both columns' background will be compatible.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be useful if the main background is black.

Answer (score 8):

In my `_vimrc`, here is the setting:

```
highlight LineNr guibg=grey
```

or

```
hi LineNr guibg=grey
```

I don't need to set fore-color, the default is yellow and it is OK for me.

Comment: There's also `CursorLineNr` instead of `LineNr` for changing the highlight of the gutter of the line that you're currently on.

Comment: @adam_0 that's cool, turns out that `set cursorline` is needed as well for highlighting the line and wasn't on by default (at least for me; vim 7.4 on CentOS)

Comment: Actually `set cursorline` seems meant for "highlighting the entire cursor line" but I seem to need it even to highlight just the gutter.

Comment: Those who use LightLine.vim can get a `CursorLineNr` highlight that reflects the current mode: `hi! link CursorLineNr LightlineLeft_active_0`

Answer (score 7):

**guibg** and **guifg** are for vims which are not in terminal. For terminal you use **ctermfg** **ctermbg**. Usually in GUI vims you have more colors support and you simply want to avoid the background.
So I usually use this:

```
highlight LineNr guibg=NONE
```