# Color of line numbers in vim hardcopy

Tags: vim

When I print from vim using `hardcopy` I get line numbers printed in red with syntax highlighting on. I tried to change the color following the suggestions here [VIM initial settings: change backgound color for line number on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250652/vim-initial-settings-change-backgound-color-for-line-number-on-the-left-side) . But it seems this would affect only line numbers on the screen. It is discussed here: http://marc.info/?l=vim-dev&m=101738036626869&w=2 that a printoption should be added to adjust the color. Since the post is older I wonder if such a feature exists today.

Comment: Which platform and which Vim version?!

Comment: Also, you could have checked the fine help for the option, and even had a look at the current implementation of the function referenced in the discussion. http://www.vim.org/sources.php

Comment: Ubuntu Linux, gvim, vim version 7.3 . I might have a look at the sources if I find time. In any case the info could be useful for others.