# Changing vim 'gutter' color

Tags: vim

See the screenshot of how I have vim configured below.  The 'gutter' i.e. where the '+' and '~' symbols appear show my git status using this amazing sublime text port for vim: https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter

[image]

How do I change the color of the gutter where there are no '+'/'~' symbols?  I.e. the grey part?  This is how you change the number column: [VIM initial settings: change backgound color for line number on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250652/vim-initial-settings-change-backgound-color-for-line-number-on-the-left-side) but I can't find how to change the 'gutter' color.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This "gutter" is called the signs column. (See `:help signs` for more information.) The highlight group associated with this column is called `SignColumn`, and can be set like this (using the example from the help section):

```
:highlight SignColumn guibg=darkgrey
```

Comment: This looks hopeful.  I'm using vim (not gvim) and this isn't doing anything (no error, it just doesn't do anything).  Maybe `guibg=darkgrey` needs to be something else?  I'll shout if I find anything.  Many thanks.

Comment: Indeed, `guibg` sets the background colour for gvim. For console vim, use `ctermbg` and `ctermfg`, etc. For full documentation, see `:help highlight-cterm`.

Comment: nearly got it (`:highlight SignColumn` is correct) but I had to do this:

`:highlight SignColumn ctermbg=DarkGreen`

Comment: How can I change the fg and bg color of the signs?

Comment: Make sure you add this setting *after* any `colourscheme` settings in your vimrc otherwise it might get reset by the colour scheme.

Answer (score 52):

To change the color in your `~/.vimrc` so that your gutter is the same color as where your line numbers show up is the following:

```
highlight clear SignColumn
```

[image]

The [git-gutter docs](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#sign-column) have some other helpful suggestions.

Comment: This has to be put _after_ any `colorscheme` definitions.

Answer (score 19):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned is to eliminate the sign column entirely and put the signs into the number column.

Adding this to your `~/.vimrc`

```
set signcolumn=number
```

produces

[image: signs in number column]

(this is using custom symbols with the [Ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#faq-change-signs) plugin in iterm Vim).

This is [available](https://superuser.com/a/558885/476802) in "full" Vim versions 7.4.2201 or newer that include the `+signs` feature (I use the version installed by Homebrew on MacOS).

Comment: @smelm I just checked, and `:help signcolumn` says "not available when compiled without the |+signs| feature". I'm on MacOS, and installed vim with Homebrew.

Comment: `signcolumn=number` has been introduced in Vim 8.1.1564: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/394c5d8870b15150fc91a4c058dc571fd5eaa97e

Comment: wow great tip! saves space from my screen ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I think you're using https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/ as your colorscheme, as I was. Another solution for this particular case is to switch to https://github.com/ericbn/vim-solarized, as @altercation's version has [a bunch of open PRs fixing that very issue](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/pull/145) and no changes in the last decade.