# How to change the color of the left gutter in VIM?

Tags: vim

In VIM, i'm using a default theme from someone else with tweaks. The color on the left
gutter is dark gray and this makes it hard to see the contents of my gutter (in this case it's `vim-gitgutter`).

Example:

[image]

How can I update the .vimrc to change this color?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing vim 'gutter' color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277241/changing-vim-gutter-color)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gutter is called the sign-column in vim. It is controlled by the highlight group `SignColumn`

Example:

```
highlight SignColumn guibg=blue ctermbg=white
```

(This needs to be placed after you source your colorscheme)

This could have been found from the vim-gitgutter [readme](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#sign-column).

Answer (score 2):

Locate the `hi SignColumn` in the colorscheme and play with the `guibg` and `ctermbg` values.